# Spring Web Socket Session throws Jackson Exception

Tags: json, spring, websocket, jackson

In chat application, there are many rooms(Map type), which consist of Strings, boolean, and `List<WebSocketSession>`.

I think the problem is `List<WebSocketSession`> can't be written to JSON.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/lobby/roomList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getRooms(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        logger.debug("RoomCtrl - getRooms");
        Map<Integer, Room> rooms = roomService.getRooms();
        Map<String, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<>();
        returnMap.put("rooms", rooms);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                returnMap,
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

This is my method to get rooms from `roomService`. What I have to do to receive that response correctly?

For giving more information to you, I post Room Class.

```
public class Room {
    private String host, title;
    private List<WebSocketSession> members = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean status;

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public List<WebSocketSession> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }
    public void setMembers(List<WebSocketSession> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }
    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `WebSocketSession` is an abstraction to send messages over a WebSocket.
In the backend you can maintain `WebSocketSession` instances (while generally you maintain some specific values of `WebSocketSession`  such as `id`) to perform some matching (who does the request and so for...) but you will never expose and send them in a JSON object to the clients.
Why send such a payload to the clients ? Why should they know the network details of the other users (IP, sessionID and so for) ? It will just create an overhead and decrease the security level of your application.

So [`WebSocketSession`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/WebSocketSession.html) doesn't implement `Serializable` and so is defacto not serializable by Jackson (that requires that as most of JSON processing API in Java).

**To resolve your issue :**

Since the users need to know the name of the other chat room users you should 
create a mapping between `WebSocketSession.id`  and their unique pseudo/username with a `Map<String, String>` for example.
And now expose `List<String> users` in the JSON object returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I know what I have to do.

Comment: You are welcome. And glad that it may have helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, WebSocketSession not json serializable, and anyway you better dont send this info to clientside.

You can use json ignore annotation here

```
@JsonIgnore
private List<WebSocketSession> members
```

so Jackson will ignore this field, when trying to serialize Room object

Comment: So, how do I get `members ` from server? Just adding `List<String> membersList` to Room class?